# is foo += 1 considered functional?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lisp

Was thinking of creating a CONS function to create a list, but then realized that im not mutating any state with foo += 1,  since its == foo = foo + 1 which is a new object

Comment: actually, `foo += foo + 1` is not `foo = foo + 1` it is `foo = foo + foo + 1`.

Comment: good point i was thinking foo += 1 in my head

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The state is changed: the value referenced with the variable `foo` changes.

This is "not functional" in any pure sense. I might be tempted to call it "confusing" ;-)

Happy coding.